# Pentaho Table Input with SQL select instructions each row, how to insert each query result in the corresponding target table, without looping?

Tags: etl, pentaho-data-integration

I'm new to PENTAHO Data Integrator

I have to get data from 100 tables on a source DB, and then insert them into the corresponding table on target DB

I wouldn't want to do 100 TableInput/TableOutput steps (one for each table)

So I created a Table Input containing 100 rows.
Each row has two columns, table name, and the specific SQL select to get de data

WAY #1 : I think I could loop through the table listing in a crafted fashion (don't know how)

WAY #2 : In order to avoid crafted looping, I found the Execute row SQL script
and I could run every Select statements
but I can't realize how to send each result set to the corresponding target table (the SQL INSERT  part)

Can anyone spot me on how to accomplish this in whichever way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I accomplished it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look into metadata-injection capabilities in PDI. You have an example in your PDI installation, in the folder samples.

Basically, you build a transformation with a Table input and Table output step, where you leave empty the tables and columns on both steps.

Then you build a second transformation to inject metadata to this first transformation:

- It reads from somewhere (files, tables, whatever works for you) the tables and columns to inject.
- Pass this information to a step to inject the metadata to the transformation.